# SQL Server 2008 change rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I have the results of a query like this (results are from a table variable):

[image]

Period field is based on user selection

I need to get the results like this:

[image]

I tried to use pivot and union (one pivot for c9 and one for c10) but in clause of pivot doesn't work with variables. I also tried using a dynamic pivot, but in SQL Server 2008 we can't use table variable in dynamic SQL. I would very much appreciate any idea that could work for this problem.

This is working:
This is working:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 'c9' as Indicator, perioada  as Perioada, 
     C9
    FROM  @Indicators 
) AS P
PIVOT
     (
       SUM(c9) FOR perioada IN ([2023 Luna 11],[2023 Luna 12])
     ) AS pv1

UNION 

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 'c10' Indicator, perioada  as Perioada,
    C10
    FROM @Indicators
) AS pv2
PIVOT
    (
      SUM(c10) FOR perioada IN ([2023 Luna 11],[2023 Luna 12])
    ) AS pv2
```

But if I try to replace [2023 Luna 11],[2023 Luna 12] with @period1, @period2 it's not working...and with dynamic sql can't use the table variable

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 is very very old... you should be looking to upgrade asap.

Comment: There's no law that you have to use table variables, if you need dynamic pivot, perhaps you can convert your code to use temporary tables. Your question doesn't differ from billions of other unpivot + pivot questions, so not sure what's the issue you're having.

Comment: @Manu, please post your current attempt to understand your problem.

Comment: *"in SQL Server 2008 we can't use table variable in dynamic SQL"* This statement is false.

Comment: *Why* do you want/need to do this in T-SQL? This looks like a presentation issue, not a SQL issue.

Comment: @ThomA he probably means he want to select data from a table variable inside dynamic sql, which isn't possible in any sql server version

Comment: You *can* if it's a table type, @siggemannen .

Comment: @ThomA that's true, forgot about those

Comment: Yes, I select data from a table variable inside dynamic sql

Comment: You need to show us... please read [mre] and update your question

Comment: Once again, don't use table variables if you need dynamic sql, or use table types as Thom wrote.

Comment: Seems like typos - it's not going return any values for `2023 Luna 11` when the period is named `2023 Month 11`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See example.
First, there used type for table variable. I think this is possible by context.

```
CREATE TYPE PeriodList_tbltype 
AS TABLE (Perioada varchar(20), Indicator varchar(20), val float);
```

Then, dynamic SQL. (Perioada, Luna ...;)

```
declare @IndicatorTbl PeriodList_tbltype;
declare @period1 nvarchar(20)='2023 Luna 12';
declare @period2 nvarchar(20)='2024 Luna 01';

-- source table variable
declare @Indicators table (perioada varchar(20),c9 float,c10 float,c11 float);
insert into @Indicators values
 ('2023 Luna 11',150, 250,3.87)
,('2023 Luna 12',457,598,4.02)
,('2024 Luna 01',557,698,5.02)
;

-- unpivot source - simplify the structure of source data 
-- with an unknown number of columns
insert into @IndicatorTbl
select * from (SELECT Perioada, Indicator, val  
FROM   
   (SELECT Perioada, c9,c10,c11
   FROM @Indicators) p  
UNPIVOT  
   (val FOR Indicator IN   
      (c9,c10,c11)  
)AS unpvt )IndUpvt;

select * from @IndicatorTbl;

-- period list filtered (between ...) 
-- string_agg not available in 2008
declare @PeriodList varchar(1000);
with lst as(
    select Perioada 
    ,row_number()over(order by Perioada) rn
    ,count(*)over() cnt
  from (select distinct Perioada  from @IndicatorTbl)t
  where  Perioada between @period1 and @period2
  )
,r as(
  select 1 lvl,rn,cnt,cast('['+Perioada+']' as varchar(1000)) lp
  from lst where rn=1
  union all
  select lvl+1 lvl,l.rn,l.cnt,cast(lp+',['+l.Perioada+']' as varchar(1000))
  from r inner join lst l on l.rn=(r.rn+1)
)
select @PeriodList=lp from r where lvl=cnt;

-- dynamic SQL
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)=
'SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT Indicator, perioada,val
    FROM  @IndicatorTbl
    where Perioada between @period1 and @period2
) AS P
PIVOT
     (
       SUM(val) FOR perioada IN (' +@PeriodList +')
     ) AS pv1';
select @sql as expr;

-- execution 
declare @paramlist nvarchar(1000);
SELECT @paramlist = '@period1 nvarchar(20),@period2 nvarchar(20)
                     ,@IndicatorTbl PeriodList_tbltype  READONLY'             
                                                                            
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @paramlist,@period1,@period2,@IndicatorTbl;
```

Outputs

Unpivoted table (@IndicatorTbl)

| Perioada | Indicator | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 Luna 11 | c9 | 150 |
| 2023 Luna 11 | c10 | 250 |
| 2023 Luna 11 | c11 | 3.87 |
| 2023 Luna 12 | c9 | 457 |
| 2023 Luna 12 | c10 | 598 |
| 2023 Luna 12 | c11 | 4.02 |
| 2024 Luna 01 | c9 | 557 |
| 2024 Luna 01 | c10 | 698 |
| 2024 Luna 01 | c11 | 5.02 |

| PeriodList |
| --- |
| [2023 Luna 12],[2024 Luna 01] |

Generated SQL query text

```
expr
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT Indicator, perioada,val
    FROM  @IndicatorTbl
    where Perioada between @period1 and @period2
) AS P
PIVOT
     (
       SUM(val) FOR perioada IN ([2023 Luna 12],[2024 Luna 01])
     ) AS pv1
```

Final output

| Indicator | 2023 Luna 12 | 2024 Luna 01 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c10 | 598 | 698 |
| c11 | 4.02 | 5.02 |
| c9 | 457 | 557 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/q0yYXUfw)

and  Erland Sommarskog [article](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html#dynsqlfundamentals)

Tested on SQL Server 2008.